# Show that the linear span of a subset is a subset of the linear span of the superset.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let V be a vector space over the universal set and S and T be two non-empty finite sets with S $\subset$ T.
Show that $<S>$ $\subset$ $<T>$ where  denotes the linear span of A.

I did something like this: since S is a subset of T, every element in S can be expressed using the basis of T, but I don't know how we can eliminate some elements from the basis of T to make the basis of S.

Also, it is not possible that their linear spans are the same?

Comment: Write down the definition of a linear span, and the definition of inclusion, then apply the assumption to these definitions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not able to understand how to go about it.

Comment: See some general advice: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**-If $S$ is a subset of $T$ , every vector in $S$ is a vector in $T$. Now $Span(T)$ is , by definition the smallest vector space containing $T$, and $Span(S)$ is the smallest vector space containing $S$ .